# How does #onmessage and #postmessage work to communicate between main thread and HTML5's webworkers?

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, web-worker

I"m learning about HTML5 workers from [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introducing-html-5-web-workers-bringing-multi-threading-to-javascript.html#fbid=x3SFEKTHrLf) and the author uses `self.onmessage` and `self.postmessage` to communicate between the main thread and the worker "because the worker cannot access the DOM." But in the below it seems like `self` is referring to both the main thread and the worker.

```
function CalculatePi(loop)
{
    var c = parseInt(loop);
    var f = parseFloat(loop);
    var n=1;

    //these errors will need more work…
    if (isNaN(c) || f != c ) {
      throw("errInvalidNumber");
    } else if (c<=0) {
      throw("errNegativeNumber");
    }

    for (var i=0,Pi=0;i<=c;i++) {
      Pi=Pi+(4/n)-(4/(n+2));
      n=n+4;
    }
    self.postMessage({'PiValue': Pi});
}
//wait for the start 'CalculatePi' message
//e is the event and e.data contains the JSON object
self.onmessage = function(e) {
  CalculatePi(e.data.value);
}
```

The above code is from a separate js file containing the worker, and I understand that the `self` in `self.onmessage` is referring to the worker receiving a message from the main thread to start calculating, but why would it use `self.postMessage` to post a message back to itself? Is the default receipt(s) of #postMessage and #onmessage include both the main thread and worker?

Later on, the author posts the calucation of pi through this function:

```
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
  document.getElementById("PiValue").innerHTML = e.data.PiValue;
};
```

How does this work when the worker isn't suppose to have access to the DOM? It clearly is using document.getElementById here.

Comment: [Using Web Workers (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: _self_ is the worker runtime, which provides mechanisms to talk to/from the main thread. _worker_ is an interface of the main thread that allows the main to talk to the worker.

Comment: how is runtime different than an interface? seems like self and worker are both the same reference to the worker thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your file worker.js think of the `self.postMessage` as the order/instruction that the worker (self) should post a message. Since it is only able to communicate with the mainJS which created it, this message goes there. :)
Also in your mainJS `worker.onmessage` should be understood as the event "a message comes from the worker".

So basically you have both options in both your scripts:
in mainJS: `worker.postMessage("message");` to send a message to the worker - and `worker.onmessage = function(event){...}` to listen to messages from the worker

in worker script: `(self or) this.onmessage = function(event){...}` to listen to messages from the mainJS - and `self.postMessage("message");` to send something back to mainJS

Comment: Oh, and your last question: no, the worker has no access to the DOM. But the mainJS has. And it simply reacts to the onmessage event by altering the DOM (adding the value of Pi).
So in your file worker.js don't try to access any DOM elements or refer to them. This won't work.

Comment: the trickiest part is that from the main file, worker.onmessage's recipient is the main thread, but in the worker script, this.onmessage's recipient is the worker. They're both the same method belonging to the same object, so why is the recipient different? is it because it's being called from different scripts?

Comment: Yes, I believe to understand it in laymen's terms (which is most of what's available to me) it has to do with where it's called. I don't think of the receipient as the same object (while it technically is) but I just keep in mind, that `worker/self.onmessage(function(e){...})` always listens to the other side.

Comment: And how can you delay that message while doing server posts? wrapping __self.postMessage("message");___ or the parent itself on a callback is proving to be very difficult.